# How to config a fan-out model in spring-integration?

Tags: spring-integration

We're creating an activity feed system, one of the processing logic is to implement 'fan-out-on-write'. We used to use Apache Storm, I'm thinking using spring-integration should be able to achieve same parallelism.

The use case is, UserA has 1,000 followers, when UserA has a new activity, notify all followers.

My current thinking is like below:

```html
<int:splitter ref="activitySplitter" method="fanOutToFollowers" input-channel="activity" output-channel="activitySplitted"/>

<int:channel id="activitySplitted">
 <int:dispatcher task-executor="executor"/>
</int:channel>

<int:service-activator input-channel="activitySplitted" ref="activityHandler" method="handleMessage"/>
```

The splitter will split `{activity}` to `[{activity, follower1}...{activity, follower1000}]`, and send to a executor channel, the service activator will store the data.

Is there any better suggestion? Thanks!